# Subtite Edit: Unable to Choose a Video Engine

Tags: windows-10, subtitles, media-player-classic

There is the option to pick a video engine in Subtitle Edit but only DirectShow and mpv are available for me. I'd like to use MPC-HC. Both Subtitle Edit and K-Lite Codec Pack with MPC are installed on my E drive. Any input will be appreciated.

OS: Windows 10 (64-bit)

 Subtitle Edit: 3.5.16

 MPC-HC: 1.9.6.41

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Himex.

This issue has been tracked on the GitHub page for SubtitleEdit. You can see some of those discussions [here](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/pull/2013) and [here](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/issues/2010).

It looks like a fix is being tested and is waiting to be added to the release version.

I saw this workaround in the bug tracker thread:

> Lokotito commented on Nov 19, 2019
>
> Open the SubtitleEdit Settings.xml file in a text editor (e.g.
> notepad), search for MpcHcLocation, and set its value to an absolute
> path. For example,
>
> C:\MPC-HC\mpc-hc64_nvo.exe For 64-bits
> Windows the file name must be either mpc-hc64_nvo.exe or mpc-hc64.exe.

The settings.xml file is located in `%appdata%/Roaming/Subtitle Edit/settings.xml`.

The unedited file contains XML. Once you find MpcHcLocation in the file, it might look like this, which is a closed tag that needs to be expanded:

```
<MpcHcLocation />
```

Edit this line only, and include the path to your MPC-HC installation. It may be different than the one I use below.

```
<MpcHcLocation>C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC64\mpc-hc64.exe</MpcHcLocation>
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be a silly question but could you tell me where to locate the settings.xml? I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: Location of mine, substitute in your own username. C:\Users\ishmael\AppData\Roaming\Subtitle Edit\settings.xml. You can get to this folder quickly by typing %appdata% as the path in a file explorer window.